# How to monitor activemq using jconsole

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

What changes need to be done in activemq 5.15.2 to monitor it using jconsole. I tried making changes in conf/activemq.xml (useJmx="true") but not able to monitor ?

Comment: AMQ is on local or remote host ?

Comment: did you see in logs  INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html